# Does the same measure (in isomorphic measurable sets) implies the same cardinality in measurable space? How about for manifolds?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be measurable space with an isomorphism which preserves the measure. If the sets $S_1\subseteq M_1$ and $S_2 \subseteq M_2$ have the same measure in each measurable space respectively, does the cardinality of two sets are same? How about for (differentiable) manifolds instead of measurable sets? (with $n$-form)

**Additional explanation.** Let $\varphi$ be given isomorphism. There is not any assumption that implies $\varphi(S_1) = S_2$. Just the measure of them are the same. That is, if $M_1 \xrightarrow[\approx]{\varphi} M_2$, $\mu_1(S_1) = \mu_2(\varphi(S_1))$ for all $S_1\subseteq M_1$ and $\mu_1(S_1) = \mu_2(S_2) \ne 0$ if $\mu_i$ is the measure of measurable space $M_i$, the question is if we obtain "$|S_1| = |S_2|$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer about manifolds, but imagine $M_1=\{1,2,3\}$ with the measure induced by $\mu(\{i\})=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if $i=3$}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Then, $T=id:M_1\longrightarrow M_1=:M_2$ is an isomorphism that preserves the measure, $\mu(\{2\})=\mu(\{2,3\})=0$ but $S_1=\{2\}$ and $S_2=\{2,3\}$ have not the same cardinality.

Comment: **Additional question.** How about if is there the assumption that says $S_i$ are not finite sets? (I am interested in the case that $S_i$ are not finite.)

Comment: @KanuKim It's very easy to extend this example to get an example where the $S_i$ are infinite...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi is right. Imagine $M_1=\{1,2,3\}\times \mathbb{R}$ with the measure given by $\mu(S)=\lambda(S\cap(\{3\}\times \mathbb{R}))$, $\lambda$ being any measure you like in the reals.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ah, I see. I misunderstood the answer.